# How to clear variables of a mat file?

Tags: matlab

I have a mat file, named `save.mat`, which has two variables. I want to clear the variables and add some other variables. How could I clear/add variables inside a mat file?

Best

Comment: See: [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) to avoid having to load data into memory.

Comment: Why do you want to keep a matfile but delete all it's content? Delete the full file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways, either through the Matlab GUI or through a script.

To do this within Matlab itself, simply navigate to the .mat file's directory, run 'clear' within your command window (make sure to save your current workspace if you need that data!), the double-click the .mat file to load it. From here you can use the workspace to delete and add variables to your heart's content.

If you want to do this in a script, set up something like this:

```
clear
load('save'); % load the .mat file
clear foo bar % removes the variables 'foo' and 'bar'
baz = 3; % adds the variable 'baz'
save('save'); % save over the old .mat file
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did the same thing it didn't happen anything. I have a mat file and it has a variable, RMode, but when I attempt to delete it using the above code it still exists in the state field. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

To add one o more variables to an existing `.mat` file, you can use the `save` function by specifying the option `-append`.

To remove one or more variables from an existing `.mat` file you can:

- load the `.mat` file into a `struct` using the `load` function: each read variable will be stored in a field of the struct
- remove from that struct the the field corresponding to the varaible you want to delete from the original `mat` file by using the `rmfield` function
- save the struct using the `save` function by specifying the option `-struct`: this will allow save the fields of a structure as individual variables

This is an example of the implementation:

```
% Define some varaible to be saved
a=1
b=2
c=3
% Save the varaibles
save('add_del.mat','a','b','c')
% Define an additional variable
d=4
% Add the new varaible to the ".mat" file
save('add_del.mat','d','-append')
% Load the ".mat" file into a struct
str=load('add_del.mat')
% Delete the field corresponding to the varaible to delete
str=rmfield(str,'b')
% Save the fields of a structure as individual variables
save('add_del.mat','-struct','str')
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But it doesn't seem to resolve my problem. I've a mat file and I want to clear its contents without converting it to a struct. But what you said is a an example converting a matfile to a struct but it doesn't affect the original mat file. How it works? Sorry I'm new to matlab.

Comment: I got it. I didn't do the last step though. Sorry. But there should be a way to directly modify contents of a mat file without converting it to a struct and then saving it. right?

Answer (score 0):

@excaza has made a good recommendation, I think.  To verify that the `matfile` command works as suggested, try the following:

```
filename = ('file.mat');
m = matfile(filename,'Writable',true);

y = 23;
m.y = y;
clear y
load(filename);
display(y);

y = 24;
m.y = y;
clear y
load(filename);
display(y);
```